# The Vox Populi badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When I'am viewing my profile, it only shows I awarded the "Vox Populi" badge on the Badges > Settings icon > All.
[image: The Vox Populi badge only shows on Badges > Settings icon > All]

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Did you see my question entirely?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I waited for just a minute and it is now ok.